# Reading from file right after Writing in it

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I wanna write in file and then read from it and print the result

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

int x,y;
ofstream fd1(argv[1]);
ifstream fd2(argv[1]);
cin>>x;
fd1<<x;
fd2>>y;
cout<<"just read "<<y<<endl;
fd1.close();
fd2.close();
return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with it? I input 123 it outputs "just read -1078463800"

Comment: You should check if your file operations completed successfully (both the creation of the streams and the read/write). My guess is the ifstream fails because the ofstream holds the file resource

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @Borgleader I thought that too and with Remy insisting on the contrary, I figured out that I was sooo wrong about that (but not about the buffering, fortunately!). Even on Windows, it is possible to do that (it's not like python or C). So I learned something today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you can open both in read & write, this write operation is *buffered*, which means that it may not be written to disk unless you flush the stream (or you close the file).

Of course the code below works perfectly:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

int x,y;
ofstream fd1(argv[1]);

cin>>x;
fd1<<x;


fd1.close();

ifstream fd2(argv[1]);
if (fd2.good())
{
   cout << "read OK" << endl;
}
fd2>>y;
cout<<"just read "<<y<<endl;
fd2.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::ofstream` and `std::ifstream` can open the same file at the same time.  I tried it on Windows and it works fine.  The real issue is the lack of buffer flushing after writing and before reading. You do not need to close the `std::ofstream`, you can just call `fd1.flush()` or `fd1 << std::flush` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's covered in my answer. You're running Linux so you can do it. On Windows you just cannot.

Comment: damn you're right! I made the wrong test. editing!!! (I tested without passing any argument so no file was open. Trapped by the OP code).

Answer (score 2):

The `fd2>>y` statement is failing because there is nothing to read from the file yet.  `std::ofstream` buffers its output, and you haven't flushed the buffer to the file on disk before trying to then read from the file.

`std::ofstream` flushes its buffer when:

1. a new line is written.
2. its `flush()` method is called, either directly or when `std::flush` or `std::endl` is streamed to it.

Try this:

```
fd1 << x << flush;
```

Or:

```
fd1 << x;
fd1.flush();
```

On a side note, you really should be checking for errors along the way.  The `std::ofstream` and `std::ifstream` constructors could fail to create/open the file.  The `<<` and `>>` operators could fail to write/read values.  All of those operations can report errors that you can check for.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x, y;
    std::ofstream fd1(argv[1]);
    std::ifstream fd2(argv[1]);

    if (!fd1.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "cannot create output file" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (!fd2.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "cannot open input file" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (!(std::cin >> x))
    {
        std::cout << "invalid input" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (!(fd1 << x << std::flush))
    {
        std::cout << "cannot write to output file" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (!(fd2 >> y))
    {
        std::cout << "cannot read from input file" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "just read " << y << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x, y;

    std::ofstream fd1;
    std::ifstream fd2;

    fd1.exceptions(std::ofstream::failbit);
    fd2.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
    std::cin.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);

    try
    {
        fd1.open(argv[1]);
        fd2.open(argv[1]);

        std::cin >> x;

        fd1 << x << std::flush;
        fd2 >> y;

        std::cout << "just read " << y << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::ios_base::failure &e)
    {
        std::cout << "error! " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your [first code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/Tfr8jvef6) with some small modifications seems does not work as expected. You see the output is not the same with the input value.Any idea?

Comment: Your example replaced `std::cin >> x` with `5 >> x`, so there is no input being read in. `x` is *uninitialized* when bit-shifting `5`, which is *undefined behavior*, and `x` is still *uninitialized* when it is written to `fd1`, which is also *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. And [if `fd1 << x ` is called other than `fd1 << x << std::flush`](https://godbolt.org/z/6EG1WP9xG), then no data could be read from `fd2` anymore. Why?

Comment: @John I already addressed that in my answer above.